# SonarQube - Rule Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

It might look like duplicate question, but i have posted the code sample suggested by sonar rule Compliant one. When evaluating the below highlighted code with SonarQube it results in squid:S1948 rule violation.

[image]

Result,

[image]

Still its a mystery that why its showing violation for compliant code, plz clarify.

**UPDATE**

transient or serializable issue not resolved even with `sonar.java.binaries`

Sonar Scan is success but throws class loader warn:

`08:26:44.984 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
08:26:44.992 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Address' is not accessible through the C
lassLoader.
08:26:44.993 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Person' is not accessible through the Cl
assLoader.
08:26:44.993 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Address' is not accessible through the C
lassLoader.
08:26:44.994 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Person' is not accessible through the Cl
assLoader.
08:26:44.994 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Address' is not accessible through the C
lassLoader.
08:26:44.997 WARN  - Class 'dummyserial/Person' is not accessible through the Cl
assLoader.
08:26:44.998 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 14 ms`

Comment: And what does the Address class look like?

Comment: How did you define the Address class ? and did you provide bytecode to the analysis ? (is your analysis run with maven or sonar runner ? and if the latter, did you provide the .class file using `sonar.java.binaries` ?)

Comment: @benzonico, i have  both Person and Address as a separate java file, scanned through sonar runner with sonar.sources=src.

Comment: If you do not provide the bytecode of the Address class file via sonar.java.binaries then symbol it not resolved by the analyzer and type is not considered as Serializable and it raise an issue.

Comment: @benzonico, no luck with sonar.java.binaries

Answer (score 5):

As previously responded, you should fill the `sonar.java.binaries` property in order to allow bytecode analysis and symbol resolution. Having this property filled, the analysis would not raise any issue on that case.

Now, it is indeed annoying that we raise an issue when we can not resolve the symbol type of a field. I created the following ticket to handle the issue: [SONARJAVA-1266](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1266)

Comment: will try with your suggestion for now and update my status, hope Sonar team will resolve this in up coming version, thanks/

Comment: have tried with `sonar.java.binaries` but still no luck, update the details in question under update header